# Display JSON Data in Forms

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am displaying data using jQuery. It was working well, but I have to get the data from both of the queries in one request and display differently form in one query and tables from other one.

```
success: function(data) {        
  var data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data['detail']);
  for (var i = 0; i < data['basic'].length; i++) {
    //var email = $(data[i].email);
    $('#staticEmail').val(data['basic'][i].email);
    $('#staticPass').val(data['basic'][i].Pass);
  }     
}
```

```php
// PHP code where I am getting the two arrays in `$json_array` successfully

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($qBasicRslt))
{
  $json_array['basic'] = $row1;
}

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($alEmailrslt))
{
  $json_array['detail'] = $row2;
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

```html
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" name="email" size="15">
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticPass" size="5">
```

JSON data

```
basic: {0: "ali@hotmail.com", 1: "12345", 2: "active", 3: "0.260000000", 4: "3", 5: "1LKHakRqzYi6K7sSDHmV3FirMUpN9YNMYQ", email: "ali@hotmail.com", Pass: "12345", status: "active", bal: "0.260000000", AccID: "3", …}
detail: {0: "Diamond (New)", 1: "2019-11-28 06:11:30", 2.....}
```

Comment: @Rory McCrossan plz tell me where i am wrong

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking to understand what the problem is. All I can say is that updating the value of the same 2 elements in a loop will only ever show you the last values in that loop

Comment: i am storing two arrays in an array. and now i want to display data from one of the two arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening in your code is that in your js for loop you are only changing the value to your inputs. So here is an example how you can show all of your data

HTML :

```
<div id="inputs">
   <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext"  name="email" size="15">
   <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" size="5">
</div>
```

JS :

```
success: function(data) {        
  var data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data['detail']);
  for (var i = 0; i < data['basic'].length; i++) {
    //var email = $(data[i].email);
    $('#inputs').append('<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="' + data['basic'][i].email + '" name="email[]" size="15">');
  $('#inputs').append('<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="'+ data['basic'][i].Pass +'" name="pass[]" size="5">);
  }     
}
```

Comment: still not displaying :(

Comment: also in php you have to push the value into array you can do it like this 
<?php   $json_array['basic'][] = $row1;  ?>

Comment: while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($qBasicRslt))
{
 $json_array['basic'] = $row1;
} this is what i am already doing

Comment: This is what you should do if you want to get all data <?php $json_array['basic'][] = $row1; ?>